# Java web service "HTTP status 404" - Eclipse, Apache, Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm really new to Java web services and Apache Tomcat. I created a dynamic web project and developed a simple application, and created a web service which uses the Tomcat v7 server. When I run the application on the server it gives me error 404.

`"http://localhost:8080"` this root URL works fine. Only the projects that I created not working at all.

UPDATE: This is the URL I'm trying to access `"http://localhost:8080/Testing/"` which will call the add method which will take 2 integer values.

This is the web.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Testing</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Axis Admin Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AdminServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AdminServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: what is the page you are trying to access? and where is it placed ? in WEB-INF? and can you share web.xml

Comment: ok, so which page do you expect to be displayed? is it index.jsp? which page contains this `add method`

Comment: I have a class call "OperatorClass" which has the add method. I have created the web service for the "OperatorClass". Im not sure which page has the add method

Comment: @prash this is the video that I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zn8vLBOEhic

Comment: your question is too broad in that case. If you want to understand and address the 404 error, you can place the index.jsp in the WebContent and retry. Since you have `<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>` 
 in web.xml, the index.jsp will be rendered . Als to your specific web.xml, you mentioned `<url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>` and redirect to Axis Servlet. But your request URL is `http://localhost:8080/Testing/` . Make your request URL to `http://localhost:8080/Testing/services/`

Comment: @prash I can access this url "http://localhost:8080/AddServiceServer/services/OperatorClass?wsdl". How can I access the URL which access 2 integers and give me the result??

Comment: how can I predict the URL ? you know better where is it located. I have to watch the entire video otherwise to answer that!

Comment: Is there a way to find that method URL? I really don't have a clue

Comment: Sorry, may be I can try it later and will update here. good learning.. In that Video, he was showing a class named `TestOperatorClassServeer.java` and creating the `OperatorClassStub` and printing the value in the console! .. oops, so he is testing the Server method printing in the console, and not as a webservice request. So you need a Webservice consumer to consume it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50926/discussion-between-prash-and-justin-roy)

Comment: other words Webservice Client

Answer (score 2):

Justin

If you access address http://localhost:8080/Testing/ and get 404 error, you can try if this address work for you: http://localhost:8080/Testing/services